# Universal Link for IOS is not working

Tags: node.js, ios9, ios-universal-links

Hi I have done with following steps to implement Universal Link for IOS.

1.My sub domain is npd.nowconfer.com, and my apple-app-site-association file contains,

```
 {
"applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID":"R3UDJNSN2P.com.sampleUniversal.teledna",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this file is uploaded into my subdomain npd.nowconfer.com and its serveing over https.

2.I tested using AASA Validator i.e https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox and i got Test result as all pass.[image]

you can see attached screenshot.

3.Now In app side,my colleague did configuration such as

- Added the domain to Capabilities i.e **applinks:nowconfer.com**   and **applinks:npd.nowconfer.com**

Handled Universal Links in app i.e in delegate like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
    NSURL *url = userActivity.webpageURL;
    // handle url
}
```

4.my universalink is **https://npd.nowconfer.com:5000/calendar/deeplink?url=nowconfer**    when i click on this link from email ,my app is not opening instead it is redirecting to app store(becasue server side request came handling to redirect app shore if app is not installed on device)

But when i tested universalink validator here https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool  ,i have got some error

**Link to Application : Error no apps with domain entitlements
The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.**

I have seen lot of tutorials but not used anything for me.Can you guys help me to figure out what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Universal Links have to be standard `http://` or `https://` links. This means they need to use the standard web ports, of which `5000` is not one. That is why your link is not working — it's not actually a valid Universal Link.

The Apple validator checks for some additional things, and is also somewhat unreliable. This particular error message is confusing, but it has nothing to do with whether your Universal Linking configuration is correct. What it actually means is Apple can't detect `applinks:` entitlements *and* 'proper' handling of passed-in link values in the version of your app that is currently live in the App Store. This is expected if you are just implementing Universal Links for the first time. You don't need to worry about this — a number of large and successful apps with working Universal Links implementations fail this step too.

Comment: Thank you Alex.Is it compulsory App should be in APP store? ,without live app we cannot test universal link?

Comment: No, it is not necessary for the version of your app in the App Store to have Universal Links enabled. You can test with just a local build, even if your app is not in the App Store at all

Comment: Okay Thank you again.I will test today same then I will let you know on this.

Comment: Hey Alex,Now my universal link i.e https://npd.nowconfer.com/deeplink?url=nowconfer   is working one side what i mean is ,app is installed in device and if i click on link ,my app is successfully opening but after uninstalling same app the website is not loading .I dont know what is problem.

Comment: can i need to add other parameters in apple-app-site-association file?

Comment: The is no reason why your website behavior should be affected by whether the app is installed. There are no other parameters needed, and in fact none are even allowed

Comment: I am also not getting ,actually app is not installed in device ,so click on link ,it is directly displaying contents of apple-app-site-association file instead of loading website.

Comment: That sounds like a configuration issue on your server, not a problem with Universal Links specifically

Comment: I noticed that if app is installed ,on click on universal link request will not landing to my endpoint it will open app as expecting so its fine ,suppose if is not installed in device I will handle to redirect to my store.I think it will solve my all issues.Thank you Alex for your great support.

Comment: @SantoshKhavekar is the issue fixed?